# CSS: Change direction of text overflow without changing text order

Tags: html, css, text

I've got some text and I need it to overflow off the **left side** of its container (I hide the overflow). Basically, I want it to look like this:
[image]

Apparently, you have to you `direction: rtl;` to do this. **[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/StkjT/2/)**

The problem is that **this changes some of the order of the text**: `hello, world?` is displayed as `?hello, world`, and `1+2=3` is displayed as  `3=1+2`.

I've tried playing with the `unicode-bidi` property, but I can only get that to put things *completely* right to left.

So, here's the actual question: **How can I get text to overflow off the left side of its container without reordering the text?**

Comment: Can you post an example of "expected output"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
text-align:right;
white-space:nowrap;
overflow:visible;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. See [forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6JF9T/1/). Again, the idea is to make the text overflow off the *left* side, not the right.

Comment: If you don't specify the h1 width and make it float right. It will overflow on the left side. Would that be what you are looking for ? http://jsfiddle.net/6JF9T/3/

Comment: Ah, I see. That's a good start, thanks. Problem is, I need to hide the overflow text (see parentheses on first line).

Comment: The goal isn't to hide the overflow of the parent div, it's to hide the overflow of the h1.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that I can add another invisible parent element just for this purpose. So, this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific block of text you need to manipulate try the `text-indent` property with a negative value like so:

`text-indent: -20px`

This probably won't work for dynamic text though.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap the English text into a span which has direction LTR, and the overflowed text has "inline-flex" like the following:

```
<div style="direction:rtl;width:150px;overflow:hidden;text-align:right;white-space:nowrap;">
    <div style="display:inline-flex">
        <span style="direction:ltr;">Hello people, I'm asking: 1+1=2, or what???</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

You will get: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xKfGa

It is some how complicated, but I think this is the only right way, although it won't display perfectly on IE.